# How to create a new Table in SQLite database from android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I faced a problem with creating simple application, here is one of it's option:
let's say user input name and press button and application create new table in existing database with that name.
My class DBHelper contains next methods:

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_QUANTITY + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_STATUS + " INTEGER); ";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

And it works perfect under one first table, which was created at the first time with default name I specified. 
Now I create some UI and set listener to button (details are not important I guess). Listener call method:

```
     public void createTableIfNotExists(String tableName) {
         String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_QUANTITY + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_STATUS + " INTEGER); ";
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.rawQuery(query, null);

        Log.d("TEST", "createTableIfNotExists called");
    }
```

It seems like everything OK, but table are not created! I tried to call onUpdate method with incremented database version number, but still resultless. 
What should I do to solve my issue? 
Note, that number of tables could be as much as user want to create, but all they will be similar (same schema).

P.S.
once I ask this question, can anybody explain how to get list of tables from DB?
I found solution:

```
public List<String> getListOfLists() {
        ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor c = shoppingListDB.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                arrTblNames.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();
        return arrTblNames;
```

But the list it return a little bit weird: [android_metadata, sqlite_sequence, Newlist1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second instance you are using `db.rawQuery` instead of `db.execSQL`. That's why the table is not created.

Regarding the second question: Android creates the `android_metadata` table to keep track of the current database version and past updates. The `sqlite_sequence`
table is for managing `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` fields (it stores the highest available number). This is normal and they always have the same name (I believe..), just remove them from your list.

Comment: The **android_metadata** contains the **locale**. The database version number, if utilised e.g. as by the SQLiteOpenHelper *(via a subclass often termed as a Database Helper)* is extracted from the file as offset 60-63 which is officially termed the **user version**. `PRAGMA user_version;` can be used to obtain the version, `PRAGMA user_version = n;` can be used to set the version. The user version is not utilised by SQLite itself, it is provided for applications to utilise.[user_version](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version)

Comment: It seems like working solution, thanks for help and for explaining also!